# how can I find out which python virtual environment I am using?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-venv

I have several virtual environment in my computer and sometimes I am in doubt about which python virtual environment I am using.  Is there an easy way to find out which virtual environment I am connected to?

Comment: It should be displayed in the terminal like: `(env1)$`

Comment: I have many venvs and some I gave the same name and it is confusing me.  maybe print sys.executable would tell me?

Comment: @kay `print sys.prefix`

Comment: that does it.  thanks!

Comment: @Kay great, I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use `sys.prefix` to determine which virtualenv you're in.

```
import sys
print(sys.prefix)
```

from the [`sys` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.prefix)

> A string giving the site-specific directory prefix where the platform independent Python files are installed

Comment: If you need a code one-liner for the command line:
`python -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)"`

Answer (score 19):

Usually it's set to display in your prompt. You can also try typing in `which python` or `which pip` in your terminal to see if it points to you venv location, and which one. (Use `where` instead of `which` on Windows.)

Comment: On Windows this gave me a list of all available Python environments. The one at the top of the list is the current one. Might seem obvious, but wasn't to me initially.

Answer (score 18):

From a shell prompt, you can just do `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV` (or in Windows `cmd.exe`, `echo %VIRTUAL_ENV%`).

From within Python, `sys.prefix` provides the root of your Python installation (the virtual environment if active), and `sys.executable` tells you which Python executable is running your script.

Comment: This was the best answer for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```bash
echo $Env:VIRTUAL_ENV
```

if you are in Windows Powershell (which is for example the default terminal in VSCode).

Taken from Super User at [How can I display the contents of an environment variable from the command prompt in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/a/615797/1192848)

Answer (score 0):

if you used  pip install virtualenvwrapper-win   in windows and used:
mkvirtualenv <environment_name> , you can just type 'workon'  to display the virtual environments on the command line.